# How do I include the blog page in a custom WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I am pretty new to WordPress and I am trying to make a basic custom theme from scratch. The basic navigation menu is displayed and works on all of my pages except for the default blog page (which just appears as a blank white screen when clicked on). I have my theme split up into multiple files (header, footer, page, archives, etc). I think that the page.php file is what is supposed to display the blog, but it only works on the home, about, and test pages.

page.php:

```
<?php get header();?>
<div>
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>
        <?php the_content();?>
    <?php endwhile; endif;?>
</div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`post.php` is not for the post type `post` it is for static pages or custom post-types.

You are looking for `single.php` or `index.php`.

This template Hierarchy from the Wordpress docs will help you.

[image: Wordpress Template Hierarchy]

Also see: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

**Style.css**

Go to the WordPress default theme folder, open the style.css file. Copy the commented code at the top and paste it to the GlossyBlue style.css file. Change the theme name and the author information as you desire.

**Splitting The Files**

Now you need to understand where to split the file into several files: header.php, sidebar.php, and footer.php. The image below shows a simplified version of my index file and how the markups should split.

**Header.php**

Open the index.html file. Cut from the top to where the  ends, paste it in a new PHP file, and save the file as header.php.

**Sidebar.php**

Back to the index.html file, cut from where the  start to the closing tag of  and paste it in a new PHP file, save it as sidebar.php.

**Footer.php**

Back to the index.html file, cut from the  tag to the end of  and paste it in a new PHP file, save it as footer.php.

**Index.php**

Now in your index.html file, you should only have the  wrap. Save the file as index.php. Insert the line:get_header, get_sidebar, and get_footer in the same order as your layout structure.

**Single.php**

Now, it is time to do the single.php template. If you want, you can go through the same process — cut & paste from the default theme. But, I find it easier to use the index.php that you just created and save it as single.php. Open the default theme single.php file and copy the Template Tags over. Then include the comments_template. The image below highlights what I’ve changed:

**Page.php**

With the single.php template you just created, save it as page.php. Remove the post date, comment form, next/previous link… and that’s it.. there goes your page.php template.

**Detailed document here :** http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/building-custom-wordpress-theme

You question answer :

Copy page.php and rename it to single.php file.